# MassTransit Unity Example

Tags: unity-container, masstransit

I have been attempting to configure masstransit in my Web Application's UnityConfig.cs file with no success.  I have attempted several methods and read many articles, but still have not gotten it to work.  I looked at the example that is on the MassTransit site but can not seem to get it to work.  The first issue that I am having is the I cannot figure out what assembly the "TypeFinder" class lives in, nor can I find the "FindTypesWhichImplement" method.

Is the example on the masstransit page suppose to work or is it more of "This is what it may look like" example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Starbucks sample (https://github.com/MassTransit/RabbitMQ-Samples/tree/master/Starbucks) has Winsor, StructureMap, and NInject but no Unity. I don't think any of the core team uses Unity.

Though I'd start with making sure you have Unity integration NuGet package included. Check your namespaces (`using MassTransit;`). It's all extension methods, and should be in the MassTransit namespace. We might have misplaced a type in the wrong namespace somewhere but my quick check of [the source](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/Containers/MassTransit.UnityIntegration) doesn't show any.

Comment: Travis,  Thank you for the response.  I have checked my namespacing and my NuGet and all looks good.  I have been using Winsor, but there was push to move the product to Unity.  I am now looking to push back and either stay with Winsor or move to StructureMap.

Comment: +1 on structure map, only because it's my favorite :) I would post an issue on GitHub.com/MassTranist/MassTransit if you want the docs fixed for Unity.

Comment: I will look at posting on the MassTransit issue list if I have problems getting Winsor working, which should not be a problem since I already have it working on another project.  I am accepting your answer since it lead me back down the path I know well.